# Do the founders of various Vaishnavite sects describe reaching transcendent states of being after which they became teachers?

Tags: vaishnavism, enlightenment

For example, the Buddha's description of his enlightenment:

http://www.newindianexpress.com/cities/hyderabad/2013/mar/14/nirvana-in-buddhas-words-458528.html

> Let us try to understand the content of that realization in the words of the Master himself. In his very first discourse at Sarnath, Buddha expressed the content of that realization in these few simple words (Majjhima Nikdya, Sutta 26, adapted from J.G. Jenning’s translation):
>
> ‘There (at Uruvela) I settled, Bhikkhus, there being everything needed for effort. And being myself subjected to earthly existence, I perceived the wretchedness of what is subjected to earthly existence, and seeking the supreme peace of nibbanam not affected by earthly existence. Being myself subjected to decay, to disease, to death, to grief, (and) defilement, I attained the supreme peace of nibbanam not affected by decay, ---- disease, death, grief, (and) defilement.
>
> ‘And the knowledge (jnanam) now as a thing seen arose in me: “My liberation (vimutti) is established, separate existence” is terminated here; there is not now rebirth (punna-bbhavo).”
>
> Continuing further, Buddha said (ibid., Sutta 36):
>
> “Then I turned my mind to the knowledge of the destruction of the taints (asavas). I knew verily (yathabhiitam) (the four truths): “This is sorrow.” ...”This is the origination of sorrow.” ....”This is the cessation of sorrow.” ... I knew verily: “These are the taints (asavas).”
>
> ‘When thus I perceived and understood, my mind (cittam) was liberated from the taint of lust (kama-asava),.....the taint of individuality (bhava-asava); and the taint of ignorance (avijja-asava); and when I was liberated there arose in me the knowledge of my liberation. I knew: “separate existence is ended; the holy life is lived, what must be done is done; there is nothing beyond this.”
>
> This is how Buddha described the content of his realization; and it can easily be mistaken for a passage in any one of the Upanishads. Destruction of the separate ego sense, cessation of birth, attainment of perfect purity and insight -- this is spiritual emancipation according to both Upanishads and Bhagavan Buddha. Both term it mukti or nirvana, a state which ensues when avidya, spiritual blindness, along with all its effects, is completely destroyed. Says the Mundaka Upanishad (II. 2. 8):
>
> ‘The knots of the heart are cut asunder, all doubts are dispelled, (the seeds of ) all actions get exhausted, when the supreme truth of Oneness is realized.’

Are there records of how the Vaishnavite teachers achieved their illumination that led them to become teachers?

Comment: As far as Sri-Vaishnavas go, the teachers didn't suddenly become enlightened. They were staunch followers of Vedic Varna-ashrama Dharma and revered sistas. They acquired by learning at the feet of previous Acharyas. There is only one instance of "divine revelation" in the Sri Vaishnava tradition and that is Nathamuni receiving the Divya Prabandhams and initiation from Nammazhvar. Sri Vaishnava philosophy / theology is strongly based on scripture. Without the help of the Veda, it is considered that Parabrahman cannot be ever understood.